# Make React member function reusable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a member function for my react component. In that function I use set state to update component state using this.setState. Now I use the same function in all of my components. Can I make it as a common function? Then how can I access `this` for calling `this.setState` inside this common function

Comment: Suppose the function name is `updateStuff`, what you need is to bind it to the correct instance using `this.updateStuff.bind(this)` when you pass it to the child components.

Comment: Is this owner React component a parent of all the components that need to access this function? If so, you can pass it through with props and call it that way. If you need this function/state to be throughout your app, you should look into using Flux or Redux to manage state in your app.

Comment: Actually all the react components are independent. There is no parent and child relation among them. I want to import this function in all of these componemts and the function can set tje staye of these components.  @Michael Lyons

Comment: @PranavPinarayi So each component just needs the same function that will set the state of that particular component? Look into using [Higher Order Components](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/higher-order-components.html). But if this is a shared (singleton) state, then look into using [Redux](http://redux.js.org/) or [Flux](https://facebook.github.io/flux/)